# Get number which occurs after its label text in HTML

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, text-extraction

I'm using PHP to parse an e-mail and want to get the number after a specific string.

For example, I would want to get the number 033 from a string that looks like:

```
 Account Number: 033 
 Account Information: Some text here
```

The content is actually HTML, so the input string is more accurately presented as:

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000099"><strong><font color="#660000">Account  Number</font></strong><font color="#660000">: 033<br><strong>Account Name</strong>: More text here<br>
```

There is always the word `Account Number:` and then the number and then a line break. I have:

```
 preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

But that just gets all the numbers.

Comment: There are more numbers than just this in the larger string (I just took a piece) So I would only want the number after the "Account Number" and not any other numbers

Comment: They may not necessarily be in order either

Comment: That HTML is malformed btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the number is always after `Account Number:`  (including that space at the end), then just add that to your regex:

```
preg_match_all('/Account Number: (\d+)/',$str,$matches);
// The parentheses capture the digits and stores them in $matches[1]
```

Results:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Account Number: 033
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 033
        )

)
```

**Note:** If there is HTML present, then that *can* be included in the regex as well as long as you don't believe the HTML is subject to change. Otherwise, I suggest using an [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get to the plain-text version of your string and using a regex from there.

*With that said*, the following is an example that includes the HTML in the regex and provides the same output as above:

```
// Notice the delimiter 
preg_match_all('@<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000099"><strong><font color="#660000">Account 
Number</font></strong><font color="#660000">: (\d+)@',$str,$matches);
```

Comment: That's returning an empty array... Could it be that this is coming from an e-mail? I'm using quoted_printable_decode() as well: $fullBody = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$email_number, 1.0);
   $str = quoted_printable_decode($fullBody);

Comment: It could be because of hidden characters in your text. copied and pasted the text you had, and it works on www.myregextester.com.

Comment: Ah, if it is HTML then that makes more sense. Yes, those HTML characters are taken into account in the regex. If you know the html tags within that code, you could either add that to your regex if you *know* they will not change or include more attributes than they do now, or use an [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ASSUMING the HTML doesn't change, then the regex I provided in my edit will work. If it does change, you're better off using a parser before using a regex.

Comment: Yea... i figured that wasn't a good Idea. I used HTML DOM Parser that you mentioned and now I think it's all in one line... at least it looks like plain text in the browser...Here is the exact string that the parser is displaying: OUNT   Account Number: 033 Account Na...

Comment: That regex you had above doesn't seem to be working still though

Comment: Interesting, it's working for me. In regextester.com, make sure to change your delimiter to `@`, and only use this as the regex: `<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000099"><strong><font color="#660000">Account 
     Number</font></strong><font color="#660000">: ([\d]+)`

Comment: In addition, use the result of the string from the parser in my original regex.

Comment: Hmm, when I use the original regex with that string in the regex tester it works...but in PHP it's not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26755/discussion-between-josh-and-bill)

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = 'Account Number: 033 
 Account Information: Some text here';

preg_match('/Account Number:\s*(\d+)/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // 033
```

You don't need to use `preg_match_all()` also you did not put your match into a backreference by placing it within parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the HTML as the base:

```
$str = '<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000099"><strong><font
    color="#660000">Account Number</font></strong><font color="#660000">: 033<br>
    <strong>Account Name</strong>: More text here<br>';
preg_match_all('!Account Number:\s+(\d+)!ims', strip_tags($str), $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

and we get:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(19) "Account Number: 033"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "033"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@montes is appropriately calling `strip_tags()` to sanitize/simplify the input text before using regex to extract the targeted substring.  However, the pattern could use some refinement and assuming there is only one Account Number per email, you shouldn't be using `preg_match_all()`, but `preg_match()`.

- No case-insensitivity is necessary, so there is no significance to the `i` pattern modifier.
- There is no `^` or `$` metacharacters in the pattern, so the `m` pattern modifier is useless.
- There are no `.` metacharacters in the pattern, so the `s` pattern modifier is useless.
- `\K` restarts the fullstring match.  This is beneficial because it removes the necessity to use a capture group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GsuWK))

```
$html = '<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000099"><strong><font
    color="#660000">Account Number</font></strong><font color="#660000">: 033<br>
    <strong>Account Name</strong>: More text here<br>';

echo preg_match('~Account Number:\s*\K\d+~', strip_tags($html), $match)
     ? $match[0]
     : 'No Account Number Found';
```

Output:

```
033
```