# How to extract a number from a string with PHP (eg. tomatoes: 10)

Tags: php

I need to extract a number from a string, the string looks like this:

```
$string ="Thank you for your order... order date: 01-01-2019 <br> items: 12 tomatoes<br> price: 5.00 $";
```

I need to output "12" from the above string! There are lots of numbers in the string - I just need to fetch the number of items, though. The ":" and a "SPACE" after "items" is fix and can be used to identify wher the number can be found. Number range goes from 1-100.

I tried this, but it gives me all numbers:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581734/get-number-after-string-php-regex).*

Assuming the format will always "Items: " and then the number, you can use the following `preg_match`:

```
$string ="Thank you for your order... order date: 01-01-2019 items: 12 tomatoes price: 5.00 $";
preg_match("/items: ([0-9]+)/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

This will output the following values from the `$matches` array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "items: 12"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
}
```

Of which your number is `$matches[1]`.

Comment: ^^ linked dupe answer

Comment: Good spot. I will link in my answer.

Comment: If I want to use this script for the "price" instead, how can I handle the digets? I want 5.00 without the dollar sign! Is this working: preg_match_all('/items: ([\d]+)/',$string,$matches);

Comment: Change the `preg_match` to the following: `"/price: ([0-9\\.]+)/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use strpos() function to find ':' and then get next 3 characters with substr() function

```
$data=substr($string, strpos($string,'items:')+7, 3);
```

this example means that from $string, find where is 'items:' located and then get next 3 characters in the variable $data

Answer (score 0):

You can also find index of the strings that can be used to extract ( sub string ) required information.

stripos()  -  first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.

strripos()  - last occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string.

```
$string ="Thank you for your order... order date: 01-01-2019 items: 12 tomatoes price: 5.00 $";
$firstIndex = stripos($string, ':');
$lastIndex = strripos($string, ' tomatoes');

$count= substr($string, $firstIndex + 2, $lastIndex )
```