# get specific part of a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I get this string, where the structur is always the same, only the content is different:

```
Herr Max Mustermann Musterstraße 3 12345 City Customer 123456 Date 03.01.2023
```

Now I would like to get the number after "Customer"
How can I realize it?
My Idea:

1. explode the string by " "
2. Loop each element and chek if value == customer
3. If yes. get next element of array -> this should be the number

Is there an better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the full string, capture the numeric substring after `Customer`, then match the rest of the string; then replace the whole string with the numeric substring.  Done.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/o0u05))

```
$string = 'Herr Max Mustermann Musterstraße 3 12345 City Customer 123456 Date 03.01.2023';

echo preg_replace('/.* Customer (\d+).*/', '$1', $string);
```

---

You could use `preg_match()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15581789/2943403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475725/2943403), but that would involve creating an array, then accessing the string from the array (meaning it is less direct coding practice).

If you *actually* want to parse more than a single value, then it makes sense to use `preg_match()` to capture the desired substrings.