# How can i replace all specific strings in a long text which have dynamic number in between?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am trying to replace strings contains specific string including a dynamic number in between.
I tried *preg_match_all* but it give me **NULL** value

Here is what i am actually looking for with all details:

In my long text there are values which contains this `[_wc_acof_(some dynamic number)]` , i.e: [_wc_acof_6] i want to convert them to `$postmeta['_wc_acof_14'][0]`

This can be multiple in the same long text.

I want to run through with this logic:

1- First i get all numbers after `[_wc_acof_` and save them in array by using ***preg_match_all*** as guided here [get number after string php regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581734/get-number-after-string-php-regex)

2- Then i run a foreach loop and set my arrays for *patterns* and *replacements* with that number i.e:

```
foreach ($allMatchNumbers as $MatchNumber){
  $key = "[_wc_acof_" . $MatchNumber. "]";
  $patterns[] = $key;
  $replacements[] = $postmeta[$key][0];
}
```

3- Then i do replace with this `echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);`

> But i am unable to get preg_match_all it gives me **NULL** where i tried below

```
preg_match_all('/[_wc_acof_/',$string,$allMatchNumbers );
```

**Please Help? i am not sure if preg_grep is better than this?**

Comment: `[` is special, escape it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok sir let me try this

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried this sir 
preg_match_all('/_wc_acof_/',$html,$matches);
die(var_dump($matches));

But still empty array() :-(

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/pgZOY, I think you need something like this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So nice of you let me try this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir here i tried your code with my case, it gives some issue https://3v4l.org/pnYmD

Comment: It is due to the fact that the `$replacements` array does not contain the `9` and `11` keys. See https://3v4l.org/0X3Qa. What is the expected behavior if the keys are not present?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i got the point, but actually i never know what is the replacement so i can not setup replacement array until i know the digits first. Can i get all digits only in array by preg_match or some thing in this way i can setup $replacements array as you guided

Comment: Sure, see https://3v4l.org/MTvYF

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much! i have applied the same here and i guess this is what i am looking for, https://3v4l.org/EeUlW now going to apply in my code.

Comment: Please add the code you will come up to in the question and let me know, I think you are overcomplicating this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir its achieved from your code successfully, actually their is a front end of this where user can enter this tag in his html like this [_wc_acof_6] , that number can be any as each user can have many fields so this is a field number. On the back end i convert this tag into the required variable to give him the value of that field.

Comment: What I mean is https://3v4l.org/kP2eI. If you have an array of known IDs, you can handle them but if the ID is missing in the `$replacements`, you can just keep the match as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to process the input in stages, to obtain all the numbers in specific lexical context first, and then modify the user input using some lookup technique.

The first step can be implemented as

```php
preg_match_all('~\[_wc_acof_(\d+)]~', $text, $matches)
```

that extracts all sequences of one or more digit in between `[_wc_acof_` and `]` into Group 1 (you can access the values via `$matches[1]`).

Then, you may fill the `$replacements` array using these values.

Next, you can use

```php
preg_replace_callback('~\[_wc_acof_(\d+)]~', function($m) use ($replacements){
    return $replacements[$m[1]];
}, $text)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MTvYF):

```php
<?php
$text = '<p>[_wc_acof_6] i want to convert this and it contains also this [_wc_acof_9] or can be this [_wc_acof_11] number can never be static</p>';

if (preg_match_all('~\[_wc_acof_(\d+)]~', $text, $matches)) {

    foreach($matches[1] as $matched){
        $replacements[$matched] = 'NEW_VALUE_FOR_'.$matched.'_KEY';        
    }
    print_r($replacements);
    echo preg_replace_callback('~\[_wc_acof_(\d+)]~', function($m) use ($replacements){
        return $replacements[$m[1]];
    }, $text);
}
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 11
)
NEW_VALUE_FOR_6_KEY i want to convert this and it contains also this NEW_VALUE_FOR_9_KEY or can be this NEW_VALUE_FOR_11_KEY number can never be static
```